# Hibernate Initial SessionFactory creation failed

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, liferay

I'm trying to use hibernate to fill my jsf `selectonemenu` in `ApplicationBean` (in Liferay). The problem is that I got Initial `SessionFactory` creation failed problem. Before putting my functions in the applicationbean I was setting them in sessionbean and I got no error.

For now the full error

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed. 
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.type.StringType cannot be cast to org.hibernate.type.VersionType
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have very likely a `VARCHAR` column called `VERSION` somewhere and Hibernate's reverse engineering tool generates it as:

```xml
<version name="version" type="string">
    <column name="VERSION" length="20" />
</version>
```

instead of:

```xml
<property name="version" type="string">
    <column name="VERSION" length="20" />
</property>
```

The former is wrong. First, I think that this is not what you want. Second, a string is not allowed for a version field as mentioned in the chapter [5.1.9. Version (optional)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-version):

> Version numbers can be of Hibernate type `long`, `integer`, `short`, `timestamp` or `calendar`.

This problem has been somehow reported in [HHH-3002](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3002) (actually, it should be assigned to Hibernate Tools, not Hibernate Core) and I see two ways to solve it. Either

- fix the mapping manually
- rename the column to something else.

Answer (score 1):

The property on one of your domain classes that you've mapped as the class's version is of type string. This is not a valid type for a version. What to change it to will depend on how you are implementing versioning in your underlying database.

Comment: look I'm using netbeans to autogenrate hibernate configuration and mapping file. Is there a way to find where is the error?